# Accessing an implemented abstract property in the constructor causes CA2214: Do not call overridable methods in constructors

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, virtual, code-analysis

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    public abstract bool MyProperty
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
}

public class MyClass : MyBase
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        this.MyProperty = true;
    }

    public override bool MyProperty
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
}
```

The constructor MyClass() causes CA2214:

> *Do not call overridable methods in constructors.*

This normally only shows if one calls a virtual method defined in the same class as the constructor. e.g. Accessing `MyProperty` inside `MyBase`'s constructor. Here I am calling a **non-virtual overridden implementation** of an inherited abstract property inside the derived class' constructor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's still virtual, as `override` doesn't seal the member implicitly. (Try it: derive another class from `MyClass`, and you can override `MyProperty` again.)

You could seal it explicitly though:

```
public override sealed bool MyProperty
{
    get;
    protected set;
}
```

At that point I'd expect the warning to go away.

Comment: I though everything had to be explicitly declared virtual including overridden members.

Comment: @Kurian: Nope. In fact, you *can't* specify both `override` and `virtual` in the same method.