# Setting value of inherited trivial property in the constructor triggers Code Analysis Warning CA2214

Tags: c++-cli, clr, code-analysis, managed-c++

I define an interface containing a trivial/simple property and an implementing class that sets the property in its constructor:

```cpp
    interface class IMyInterface
    {
    public:
        property System::String^ MyName;
    };

    ref class MyImplementingClass : public IMyInterface
    {
    public:
        virtual property System::String^ MyName;

        MyImplementingClass()
        {
            MyName = "Test Name";
        }
    };
```

This doesn't seem too contentious, but when I run Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2019 using the default *'Microsoft Mixed (C++/CLR) Recommended Rules'* ruleset it triggers warning CA2214:

```
warning CA2214: Microsoft.Usage : 'MyImplementingClass::MyImplementingClass(void)' contains a call chain that results in a call to a virtual method defined by the class. Review the following call stack for unintended consequences: 
warning CA2214: MyImplementingClass..ctor()
warning CA2214: MyImplementingClass.set_MyName(String):Void
```

So I think it's complaining because setting this property involves calling the automatically implemented method `set_MyName()` and since that method is virtual [it is considered a violation to call it from a constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2214?view=vs-2019).

Does that mean this whole pattern is invalid?

**What is the *correct* way to set the value of an inherited property at construction time?**

Comment: Exact same case as the question that's linked in the Related list.  An auto-implemented property is implicitly sealed in C++/CLI, so it can't go wrong, but the code analyzer doesn't know that.  You could disable the rule, ignore it, or declare the class `sealed`.

Comment: @HansPassant: You mean same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/17018569/79591 ? Thanks, I hadn't seen that one as I was looking at C++/CLI rather than C#. Not sure that there is any way to seal a simple/trivial property in C++. Unless I am missing something it looks like I have to explicitly declare the accessors and backing storage to do that. Yuk!